# How can I prevent one ArrayList changing another

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, nested-lists

I have two identical `ArrayList`s, say `l1` and `l2`.

Both are multi-dimensional, for instance `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.

When I create and populate `l1`, I'm using `new ArrayList<>(l1);` to initialize `l2`. If these were `ArrayList`s of a single dimension, me editing `l2` would leave `l1` unchanged, but since they are not, adding a new `Integer` to `l2` also changes `l1`. If I were to add a new `ArrayList` to it, though, `l1` wouldn't do anything.

What can be done to make sure that changing an element in `l2` doesn't tamper with `l1`?

*Example:*

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l1 = new ArrayList<>();

for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
  l1.add(new ArrayList<>());

  for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    l1.get(x).add(y);
  }
}

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(l1);

//Should not change l1
l2.get(0).add(999);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating this two arrays. We are only creating two new Objects of ArrayList but not creating a new Instances of the Objects inside the List. So whatever is inside of this two ArrayLists if L1 make a change L2 will reflect the change because this two ArrayLists are referring the same Object in the Memory.

For make this work don't initialize like this way

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(l1);
```

Iterate over l1 and create new Objects.

Comment: Thank you, this does work, the only thing is that method is a little inefficient (this will happen every epoch in a neural network), but if it has to be done it has to be done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Copy-constructors in the Collection framework always perform a shallow copy, **not** a deep copy, as you've probably expected.

Javadoc of the [`ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Collection)) says:

> Constructs a list containing the **elements** of the **specified collection**, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.

Namely, the resulting list would contain exactly the **same** elements, not their copies. I.e. in your case, references the same inner lists.

Hence, you need to copy each element in the nested list manually:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> copyNestedList(List<List<T>> list) {
    
    List<List<T>> copy = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<T> l: list) {
        copy.add(new ArrayList<>(l));
    }
    return copy;
}
```

If you're comfortable with Stream API, you can do it like that:

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> copyNestedList(List<List<T>> list) {
    
    return list.stream()
        .map(ArrayList::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you yes this is what I have ended up doing. The non-example array is a neural network so it has a fair few more dimensions but thankfully the loops don't seem to slow down optimisation too much.

Comment: @Gamaray There's no clean and simple way to make a deep copy of a nested `List` having arbitrary depth. As far as performance is concerned, plain loops are the best tools you can use.

Answer (score 1):

You could manually create a new list without referencing the original one

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l1 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
      l1.add(new ArrayList<>());
    
      for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
        l1.get(x).add(y);
      }
    }
    
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0;i < l1.size(); i++){
        
        ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for (int j = 0;j < l1.get(i).size(); j++){
            
            tmp.add(l1.get(i).get(j));
        }  
        l2.add(tmp);
    }
```